# Java/Android Decent XML Reading API

Tags: java, android, xml, api

Is there any decent API to read xml string data like we do using JQuery or with DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, I have found [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to be by far the simplest.

[Here's a simple example](http://earldouglas.com/barebones-spring-mvc/restful-web-services), and you'll find all kinds of useful snippets on Stack Overflow.

[This example](http://earldouglas.com/a-secure-restful-web-service) goes into detail about working with XSDs and generating JAXB annotations from sample XML.

Comment: JAXB is simple if the XML is simple and if it doesn't use mixed content (for example, simple configuration files). It can get horrendous with some of the industry-standard XML vocabularies that have 1000 element types in their schema, and it's best avoided if you're handling "document-oriented" rather than "data-oriented" XML.

Answer (score 0):

First advice: don't use DOM. Libraries like JDOM or XOM do the same job much more elegantly and efficiently.

If you can avoid Java and write the whole application in XSLT or XQuery, then do. It's another language to learn, but it's much better suited to XML.

If it really has to be Java, then make maximum use of XPath, or XQUery if the queries are complex. The JAXP API for XPath is rather clunky (e.g very weak type-checking) and only supports XPath 1.0; Saxon's s9api interface is much cleaner and supports XPath 2.0, but of course you may want to avoid the lock-in.